# calculate textboxes for each table row in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am looping through a set of dynamic table rows, I am trying to capture the value of cell2 in each table row using jquery, but it returns the value of cell2 row1 every time, even though it recognises cells1 correct row value each time, can anyone tell me were I am going wrong please?  see below sample code.

Thanks for any help received.

```
//html
<table class=plantTable>
<tr>
<td><input type=text value=0 class=cell1></td>
<td><input type=text value=0 class=cell2></td>
<td><input type=text value=0 class=cell3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type=text value=0 class=cell1></td>
<td><input type=text value=0 class=cell2></td>
<td><input type=text value=0 class=cell3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type=text value=0 class=cell1></td>
<td><input type=text value=0 class=cell2></td>
<td><input type=text value=0 class=cell3></td>
</tr>
</table>

//jquery
   tr = $(".plantTable tr").length;

   $(tr).each(function () {
      $(this).find($(".cell1").blur(function () {
      cell1val = parseInt($(this).val());
      cell2val = parseInt($(".cell2").val());  //Returns the value of cell2 in the first row only?
   }));
```

Comment: `tr` is equal to an integer, `tr = $(".plantTable tr").length;`

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GCdpA

Answer (score 0):

Inside the find you're finding again, which will look at the document from the top, thus finding row1 cell2. If you want the sibling of your current item as you seem to, do this:

```
   $("tr").each(function () {
      $(this).find($(".cell1")).blur(function () {
         cell1val = parseInt($(this).val());
         cell2val = parseInt($this.siblings(".cell2").val());
      });
   });
```

This will retrieve the value of the cell2 next to the cell1 currently found.

Comment: You have a bracket mismatch.

Comment: Eh wow... lots of things were wrong actually. Thanks Ben... All copy-pasted.

Comment: Thanks Spork, tried the above solution but cell2 val returns NaN, which is strange as they have numerical values.

Comment: I see. The cell2 wasn't a direct sibling like I thought, since you are naming your inputs cell1, 2 and so on. I thought you had named your td's this way.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/VqZmw/5/

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery should look like this:

```
$('.plantTable tr').each(function () {
    $(this).find('.cell1').blur(function () {
        cell1val = parseInt($(this).val());
        cell2val = parseInt($(this).siblings(".cell2").val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Pretty sure you did the same thing :D
$(this).find($(".cell1").blur(function () {

vs.

$(this).find($(".cell1")0.blur(function () {

or most likely actually .find('.cell1')......

Comment: Good call - I missed that!

Comment: Cheers BenM, tried the above solution but still selects the first row value of cell2, weird.  Will have to rethink this.

Answer (score 0):

About solutions does your Job perfectly, but I doubt them whenever a new element is added to it. Below code will work fine even if some other input element is added in future..

```
 // If you want to maintain resusable collection of all inputs inside  
 var inputCollection = $([]).pushStack($("table.plantTable :input"));
 // Then do operations with inputCollection
 // Else, you could follow chaining like below  

 $("table.plantTable").delegate("input", "blur", function() {
    var inputs = $(this).closest('tr').find(':input');
    // do whatever you want to with inputs
 });
```